# How to write to stdin of execved process?

Tags: c, exec, stdin

I'm trying to `execve` a process that reads from stdin. I want to prepare stdin with some data so it can execute successfully. How can I do that?

Comment: `man 2 pipe` will show you how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to fork the execve call into a child process and then create a pipe from the parent process to the child's stdin.

Take a look at this link for a detailed example on how to use pipes: http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html