# how to completely close the file write before starting another process which uses it?

Tags: c, linux

My program creates a linux shell file, then it call 'popen' to execute it. To my surprise from time to time I am getting the following message:  `/bin/bash: bad interpreter: Text file busy`. So, am looking for a way to solve this problem. Any suggestions?

Here is a skeleton code of what i am doing:

```
FILE *f = fopen(shFile, "w");
fprintf(f, ...);
...
fclose(f);

FILE *job = popen(shFile, "r");
...
```

So, both processes run on the same machine, there is no 'nfs' involved, but still the popen process thinks that the file is opened for write, even after i did close. So, some system buffers are not flushed yet.

It looks like `sync()` works (though it is difficult to tell). However it slows down everything significantly.

Comment: *However it slows down everything significantly.* - That's the idea. It is synchronizing your "fast" part (the program logic) with the "slow" one (the disk IO).

Comment: you'd be better off feeding bash with the commands in standard input instead of writing a file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611457/how-to-write-to-stdin-of-execved-process. Alternately, have you tried `/tmp` to write your temp bash file ?

Comment: If your shell script is not too large (up to a few dozen kilobytes, on most modern systems), you can pass the entire shell script to the shell process using `/bin/bash -c`; that avoids the need to write a file to disk at all. (That is: use `execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", "-c", entire_shell_script_in_this_string, (char*) NULL)` or something equivalent to that.)

Comment: I think it won't happen if you popen `/bin/bash file.sh` instead of directly popening `./file.sh`.

Comment: @zch I tried it, so far there is no message. But.. the question is - why? Is there a guarantee that bash reads the whole file, not a truncated version of it?

Comment: there may be a difference between executing a file or passing it as a data file to bash.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes, i was thinking about streaming command to stdin, but there is another reason for having the file (and not in /tmp). So, i was hoping to get away with the file onlly.'

Comment: maybe you can create in /tmp then copy somewhere else, but execute in /tmp...

Comment: @Serge, it appears that the message comes from kernel trying to 'run' file (reading shebang and applying it), not from bash itself. It seems that it requires the file to be synced, perhaps to avoid some race conditions. The same doesn't apply to data files, so if it is opened by bash it causes no problems.

Comment: And you are safe about having whole file. After your process writes the file (which is completed after `fclose`), the changes will be visible to other processes even if they aren't yet written to permanent medium.

Comment: You're not checking the return code for `fclose`, which leaves open the possibility that the call failed, perhaps with error `EINTR`. I'm not saying that is what is happening, but it seems to me to be at least worth checking for.

Comment: If you are running this under linux, the `sync()` doesn't do any good here, except of change the timing a bit. It looks, that there is some level of concurrency involved, the dots probably hide some thread or fork()ing code. A real MCVE or some more context will probably reveal the nature of your problem.

Comment: @zch I think that you are correct. The kernel must guarantee that the file is available for read after writing. so, `/bin/bash file` should work. Indeed, i do not see the message or any indication of truncated files.

Comment: @rici I tried your suggest, the return status of `fclose` is '0' even when job fails.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider `fopen` did not fail.

Comment: @Serge: That's cool. I still think it is worth doing the check :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you leave the kernel to determine the interpreter to be used with a script file using a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), the kernel must take a similar "lock" on the script file as it does for binaries. (This is a kernel-internal "lock" that you can only *observe* from userspace. If the file is open for writing by anyone, the lock fails with `ETXTBUSY`.)

It is trivially to avoid that. You are free to edit script files even when they are being interpreted, if you execute the interpreter instead with the script name as a parameter.

In OP's case, it means executing `bash %s`, where `%s` is replaced with the contents of `shFile`. This also means the file referred to by `shFile` does not need to be executable; only readable.

If we assume `shFile` does not contain any `'` characters, then in Linux it is sufficient to use

```
char *jobcmd = NULL;
FILE *job;

if (asprintf(&jobcmd, "bash '%s'", shFile) == -1) {
    /* Typically an out of memory error. */
    fprintf(stderr, "%s.\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

errno = ENOMEM;
job = popen(jobcmd, "r");
if (!job) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot execute %s: %s.\n", shFile, strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

free(jobcmd);
jobcmd = NULL;
```

In general, you should consider a custom routine that constructs the sh shell command needed to execute the desired interpreter with the file name as a parameter, applying any escaping as necessary. (In POSIX sh shells, you can escape single quotes in a single-quoted string using `'"'"'`.)

---

If the script is executed only once, a custom replacement for `popen()`/`getline()` or `fread()` or `fgetc()`/`pclose()` can be used to write the script to the standard input of the interpreter (here, `bash -s`), while also retrieving the output of the script into a single array, line per line (perhaps using a callback function?), or character-by-character.  This approach has the benefit of the script never being stored on any filesystem.

---

In general, it is much more common, and definitely recommended, to install the scripts as part of the binary, and supply any specifics to it via command-line parameters (for example, `bash /usr/share/yourapp/somescript.bash 'arg1' 'arg2'`).

In Linux and BSDs, these scripts are usually put somewhere under `/usr/lib/yourapp/` or `/usr/share/yourapp/`.

Comment: yes, i started using the interpreter directly and it seems to work. I guess, my concern was about write/read kernel/user space buffering. I want to make sure that the sequence is guaranteed between sequential writer and reader processes after 'fclose' on the writer side. It looks like kernel buffering of disk files should provide it, though i could not find direct confirmation. Just want to make sure that the interpreter sees non-truncated version of the file.

Comment: @Serge: No, it's not that. The kernel-internal "lock" is at fault here. Because `fopen()` never uses the `O_DIRECT` flag, whatever has been written or flushed using the [`write()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) syscall on the underlying file descriptor, will be what is visible to the script interpreter (unless it uses `O_DIRECT`).  This is true even if the script file never reaches actual file storage media, and is only in RAM cache. This is because without `O_DIRECT`, whatever part is already in page cache, is what is visible to all readers on the same machine.

Comment: (Including read-only memory-mapped files, and the parts of memory-mapped files that haven't been modified by any memory map.) The GNU C library in particular will do the necessary `write()`s at `fclose()` time, so for the pattern shown in your question, the kernel-internal binary-executable "lock" is the only issue (as it happens to affect also scripts executed directly, naming their interpreter via the shebang line). I suspect the reason you're seeing the effect of the kernel-internal lock is that it is a bit slow detecting close-when-writable, just like e.g. inotify and fanotify are.

Comment: (And that slowness is perfectly acceptable, because it ensures no false positives occur; it is erring on the side of caution, really. The reason `sync()` (or `fsync()`) helps is probably because they take long enough for the close-when-writable information to fully propagate.)

Comment: When is this lock released? Why later than last `close`?

Comment: So, if i interpret your reply correctly, the interpreter should never read a truncated file in this case. right?

Comment: @Serge: Correct.

Comment: @zch: It is not a lock per se; that's why I use "lock" in quotes. It is actually just a check if the `i_writecount` flag for the kernel `struct inode` for the file is zero or not. The C library `fclose()` function uses `close()` syscall to close the underlying file descriptor. In the Linux kernel, the file descriptor is immediately removed, but the cleanup work is done in a separate workqueue: see [`fs/file_table:fput()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/file_table.c#L280). The `i_writecount` is updated when that workqueue gets there, which is very soon but not immediately.

Comment: @zch: (Specifically, the workqueue runs [`fs/file_table.c:delayed_fput()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/file_table.c), which calls `fs/file_table.c:__fput()` on each closed descriptor; and that calls `include/linux/fs.h:put_write_access()` for each descriptor that was open for writing, and that decrements the inodes `i_writecount` atomically.)  So, simply put, because the kernel uses a separate workqueue for internal cleanup work, the kernel will only note the last close()-was-writeable after the corresponding workqueue cleanup work has completed.